# What do hackers mean by leaving traces?

Tags: databases, tracking

Often in movies or other stories you hear hackers (or the ones fighting the hackers) about not leaving traces or finding the traces.

What exactly is meant by this? Is every action you make on a system saved in a database? And if it is, is this a standard security? If I install a MySQL database for example, does it automatically save every query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they mean that they do not want their actions to show up in logs.

These logs do not necessarily need to be saved in a database, they could also be saved in a file. The file could also be on a remote server or otherwise not writable by the attacker, making it more difficult to hide their attack.

But no, MySQL does not log queries by default (you can turn logging on though, which may be helpful in some situations, but it's mostly redundant if your server logs requests). The server will commonly log requests by default, as will (web application) firewalls (at a very minimum, suspicious requests will be logged).